# I can not create thread in the window service

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading

I am at an impasse.
Just make a service which does something every 10 sec for example.
At first I have used System.Timers.Timer for it. and all was ok on my PC. But I had faced with problem on Windows Server 2003 server of my customer. System.Timers.Timer timer1_Elapsed not firing and I have changed this timer for System.Threading.Timer and I see the same picture. It works on my PC and doesn't work on customer's server.
After I drop all both these timers and have used a BackgroundWorked for this task
Code:

```
public partial class XXXService : ServiceBase
{
    public XXXService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("XXXSource1"))
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("XXXSource1", "XXXLog");
        EventXXXLog.Source = "XXXSource1";
        EventXXXLog.Log = "XXXLog";
    }

    private ManualResetEvent threadSleepEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private BackgroundWorker fBg = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EventXXXLog.WriteEntry("XXX Service has started.");

        //fTimer.Enabled = false;
        //fTimer.Interval = 1000;
        //fTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fTimer_Elapsed);
        //fTimer.Start();

        //fTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(fTimer_Elapsed), null, 1000, 5000);

        fBg.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(fBg_DoWork);

        EventXXXLog.WriteEntry("XXX Service has started. test 2");
        fBg.RunWorkerAsync();
        EventXXXLog.WriteEntry("XXX Service has started. test 3");
    }

    void fBg_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //EventXXXLog.WriteEntry("test 4");
        lock (EventXXXLog)
        {
            EventXXXLog.WriteEntry("test 4");
        }
    }
}
```

All the same. All is ok on my PC, but it doesn't work on Server 2003 comp. I am seeing a test 1, test 2 and test 3 log messages and doesn't see 'test 4'. It seems that the BackgroundWorker doesn't execute fBg_DoWork.

What is the cause? Any ideas?

Comment: This is likely only moderately useful, but you may consider the possibility of a configuration issue with the 2003 machine.  At the very minimum, I'd try this on a clean 2003 installation.

Comment: is that the *exact* code you've been running - or have you trimmed it down to post it?

Comment: @RobLevine Yes, I have trimmed.

Comment: I'm wondering if you've trimmed out something that might explain this - I can't see anything wrong with the sample there. Does this exact code above still exhibit the problem?

Comment: @RobLevine, yes thanks. I have found the cause of this bug. I had forget to delete a reference to one object which is used in Application mode (not service). I don't know how to close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Are u getting log before

lock (EventEDILog)

Because if EventEDILog is being lock by another thread and never unlock 
then your BackgroundWorker will be blocked for the EventEDILog to get unlocked.

Comment: I have tryied and with 'lock' and without 'lock'. All the same. :(